# About the "out" prefix of function param in C#

Tags: c#, .net

```
namespace ...
{
  class Class1
   {
    public void test(out int a){
        a = 1;
        return;
    }

}
```

}

```
static void Main()
{
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();
    int a=1;
    c1.Test(a); 
}
```

compile error:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'ConsoleApplication1.func1.Class1.test(out int)' has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: @mclaassen: Says who?  It's no different from `int a = 1; a = 5;`  Perfectly legal to write to a variable more than once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ref and out? (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516882/what-is-the-difference-between-ref-and-out-c)

Comment: @BenVoigt Ya nevermind, what I really had in my head that you must assign it a value in the function.

Comment: Can you please clarify what additional information about [out (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx) you need?

Comment: Next time please **read the documentation**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it for you:

```
static void Main()
{
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();
    int a=1;
    c1.test(out a); 
}
```

When calling a function that has an `out` or `ref` parameter, you need to pay some respect to that, by marking your parameter as `out` or `ref` as well.

[MSDN Reference Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)

> To use an out parameter, ***both the method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out keyword***.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `out`keyword in the call:

```
c1.Test(out a);
```

Except of that the captialization of the name is wrong (`test` and `Test`)

Comment: I see! it's a strange syntax, unlike the c++ reference.

Comment: @lovespring: It is akin to using the address-of operator (`&`) in C or C++, when the function takes its buffer by pointer.  (And in MSIL, calling a function with an `out` or `ref` parameter does actually need an address-of instruction)