# Pass by Reference in C#

Tags: c#

How to pass a parameter as a Reference in C#  and when calling the function how should i represent it while defining that particular function

Comment: Related question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135234/difference-between-ref-and-out-parameters-in-net

Comment: Wouldn't it have been quicker to just search MSDN than post a question here and wait for the answer:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-ca/?query=Pass+by+Reference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an example of passing an int by reference:

```
void DoubleInt(ref int x)
{
    x += x;
}
```

and you would call it like this:

```
DoubleInt(ref myInt);
```

Here's an [msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(VS.71).aspx) about passing parameters.

Answer (score 11):

As others have said, you should use the `ref` modifier at both the call site and the method declaration to indicate that you want to use by-reference semantics. However, you should understand how by-value and by-reference semantics interact with the "value type" vs "reference type" model of .NET.

I have two articles on this:

- [Parameter passing in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html)
- [Reference types and value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the ref keyword to pass an object by refence.

```
public void YourFunction(ref SomeObject yourReferenceParameter)
{
    // Do something 
}
```

When you call it you are also required to give the ref keyword.

```
SomeObject myLocal = new SomeObject();

YourFunction(ref myLocal);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you take a look at [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(VS.71).aspx) about this. It's very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just add ref keyword as prefix to all arguments in the function definition. Put ref keyword prefix in arguments passed while calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

you can also reference types without need to user `ref` keyword 
For example you can bass an instance of Class to a method as a parameter without `ref` keyword