# question about ref and out

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between ref and out parameters in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135234/difference-between-ref-and-out-parameters-in-net)

in  c# there is keywords `ref` and `out` i am interesting what is difference between them? thanks