# What is the difference between ref and out

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between ref and out parameters in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135234/difference-between-ref-and-out-parameters-in-net)

I know that ref is used for passing the changed value of the variable outside of the function,
but how is it different from out?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516876/when-to-use-ref-vs-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An argument passed to a ref parameter
>   must first be initialized. Compare
>   this to an out parameter, whose
>   argument does not have to be
>   explicitly initialized before being
>   passed to an out parameter.

Answer (score 1):

An `out` parameter *must* be assigned before it can be read and before the function returns.

A `ref` parameter does not need to be assigned to before it's read or the function returns.

Consequently, a variable *must* be assigned before passing it in as a `ref` parameter, while an `out` parameter may be uninitialized before passing it in.

Answer (score 1):

A `ref` parameter allows you to pass data *in* to your function in addition to sending it *out*.

A function with an `out` parameter cannot see the parameter's initial value (the compiler considers it uninitialized)

Answer (score 1):

Specifying a parameter as `out` means that the function is required to assign a value to it before it returns. Specifying a parameter as `ref` means that a function *can* assign a value to it, but is not required to.

Note that this is just a C# convention and the runtime makes no distinction between the two.

Answer (score 0):

`ref` is used when the value of the variable going into the method is considered to be initialized and ready to be used. An example is an index in a string parsing system: a method can have a `ref int index` that will be incremented based on what the method reads.

`out` is analogous to multiple return values. The variable does not have to be initialized before calling the method, and the variable *must* be set in the called method before it returns.