# What is diffrence between Out type Vs Ref type parameter in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between ref and out parameters in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135234/difference-between-ref-and-out-parameters-in-net)

What is different between Out type and Ref type parameters in C#.net?

When we can use in which situation?

Comment: Here is the detail explanation for out vs ref 
https://youtu.be/3iRPMrNY7OU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both indicate to the caller that the method can modify the value of the parameter. `out` parameters must be initialized inside the method whereas `ref` parameters might be initialized outside. It's basically a contract. When you see a method that takes an `out` parameter this means that that caller can invoke it without initializing the value and be sure that it will be initialized inside:

```
Foo foo;
SomeMethod(out foo);
// at this stage we know that foo will be initialized
```

whereas with ref:

```
Foo foo;
SomeMethod(ref foo); // compile time error
```

It's the caller's responsibility to initialize the variable before calling the method:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
SomeMethod(ref foo); // ok
```

Comment: Here is the detail explanation for out vs ref 
https://youtu.be/3iRPMrNY7OU

Answer (score 1):

Quote from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. This is
>   similar to the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable
>   be initialized before being passed.

Some methods, like `Int32.TryParse()` use a out parameter, so one pass an unitialized variable into it.