# "ref" vs "out" keyword errors using the sql-net and C# Sqlite combination for windows phone 7.1

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, windows-phone-7

I am getting some "ref" vs "out" keyword errors using the sql-net and C# Sqlite combination for windows phone 7.1. Is this due to a wrong combination of libraries that I am using?

App Type: Windows Phone 7.1

Using:

1. sql-net Version 1.0.5, Source Nuget thru Visual Studio
2. C# Sqlite for WP7 (wp7sqlite) ( Community.CSharpSqlite.WP7) Version 0.1.1, Source Nuget thru Visual Studio.

The exact error I receive is below

> Error 5 The best overloaded method match for Community.CsharpSqlite.Sqlite3.sqlite3_open(string, ref Community.CsharpSqlite.Sqlite3.sqlite3)' has some invalid arguments
>    C:\Dev\Learning\SQLite.cs Line:2492 Column: 29

The next error then hints that it is related to the parameter being passed as "out" type instead of "ref" type.

> Error 6 Argument 2 must be passed with the 'ref' keyword C:\Dev\Learning\SQLite.cs Line: 2492 Column: 64

I can make the compile errors go away by replacing the "out" keyword with the "ref" keyword, but that is likely to lead to other issues. Given that I do not see much complain about this issue - I may be doing something wrong but not able to detect easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter  was changed in csharp-sqlite (optionally(?) used by sqlite-net) between 3.7.6.3 and 3.7.7.1 from `ref` to `out`, see [this commit](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/source/diff?spec=svn661f1640a2d917ff56c60d1e9a032b06e740bedd&r=661f1640a2d917ff56c60d1e9a032b06e740bedd&format=side&path=/Community.CsharpSqlite/src/main_c.cs) (look for line 2692).

If you don't want to update your code, you will need to use the newer version of csharp-sqlite. You probably don't see many questions about this because you're one of the few using an older version for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks. That explains the core of the problem I faced. The version of sql-net released thru NuGet has not been updated to match the C# Sqlite released thru NuGet. Given the high usage, I was not expecting that. Checking the latest source code for sql-net: It still has not been updated for these changes from CSharp-Sqlite. I will follow up with the developers of sql-net.

Comment: @param Ah, yuck, it looks like http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/ is based on an old version of http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/, and and sqlite-net uses the latter. Misleadingly, the http://wp7sqlite.codeplex.com/ code is what's available on NuGet as csharpsqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Following method signature

```
Community.CsharpSqlite.Sqlite3.sqlite3_open(string, ref Community.CsharpSqlite.Sqlite3.sqlite3)
```

Clearly states that 2nd argument is passed by reference (`ref`)

so, when calling this method use [`ref` keyword instead of `out`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516876/when-to-use-ref-vs-out)

Here also you'll find a lot of info:

[Difference between ref and out parameters in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135234/difference-between-ref-and-out-parameters-in-net)

Comment: Its probably also worth adding that if it really is important to call it with `out` instead of `ref` that you could create some kind of wrapper function that has the same signature except with `out`... I am not sure I can see what problems this could cause though so wouldn't have thought it was necessary...

Comment: @Azodious Thanks for the quick response. As you suggested and I had stated, I can make those errors go away by replacing out with ref keyword. **But that code is from open source (sql-net) and has been in use for a while without users reporting this issue**.

Comment: if it was compiling before, that means `ref` was not replaced by `out`. You need to analyze more.