# Pass an argument in static void function C#

Tags: c#, function, void

I am trying to write a C# function to determine the maximum value in an array and to pass it by reference.

It is my first time programming in C#, but it's really bugging me that I don't to seem to be able to assign it correctly in the main.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Maxim(int n, ref int maxim, params int[] v) {
            int i,  max=v[0];

            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (v[i] >  max)  max = v[i];
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            int[] vector = new int[10];
            int n, i;
            int maximul;

            Console.WriteLine("Introduceti numarul de elemente: ");
            n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Valoarea introdusa: {0}", n);
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                vector[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Elementele introduse sunt: ");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine("Elementul {0}:  {1}", i + 1, vector[i]);
            }

            Maxim(n, ref maximul, vector);

            Console.WriteLine("Maximul din vector: {0}",  maximul);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

It returns me the following error: `Use of unassigned local variable`.

Comment: Try setting maximul=0; in the declaration.

Comment: You never assign `maxim` in your `Maxim` function.

Comment: See this question's top answer for an explanation on `out` vs `ref`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135234/difference-between-ref-and-out-parameters-in-net

Answer (score 3):

Initialize your variables when you defining them :

```
int n = 0, i = 0;
int maximul = 0;
```

Probably the reason is you are passing `maximul` as **ref** parameter but you didn't initialize it.

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx):

> An argument that is passed to a **ref** parameter must be **initialized** before it is passed. This differs from out parameters, whose arguments do not have to be explicitly initialized before they are passed.

Comment: You don't need use ref in your code. Just pass value is fine. And maximul was not used at all.

Answer (score 0):

Maxim is a redundant variable. You're never using it in your function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the maximum value is being stored in the local `max` but the caller is expecting it to be written into the `ref` parameter `maxim`.  If you delete the local `max` and use `maxim` instead this will fix the problem.

A more idiomatic way to write this function is to not use `ref` parameters at all.  Instead just return the value directly

```
static intMaxim(int n, params int[] v) {
  int i,  max=v[0];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (v[i] >  max)  max = v[i];
  }
  return max;
}
```

Note that the `n` parameter is also not truly needed here.  The length of the array `v` can be accessed via the expression `v.Length`